# How to modifiy DC2259A evaluation board to access Vref2 on LTC6811-1 IC? For the purpose of powering external thermistors

Tags: voltage-divider, current-limiting, thermistor, hacking, bms

I am using a DC2259A Evaluation Board, to monitor battery cell voltages and am hoping to drive external thermistor circuits for the purpose of measuring battery cell temperatures from Vref2 on the LTC6811-1 IC (the IC at the center of the DC2259A evaluation board).

Has anyone successfully modified the DC2259A Evaluation Board to access Vref2 on the LTC6811-1? Using this modification then to drive external thermistor circuits? If so what strategy would you suggest?

link to DC2259A manual:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/dsp-documentation/evaluation-kit-manuals/DC2259AF.PDF

link to DC2259A schematic:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/eval-board-schematic/DC2259A-2-SCH.PDF

link to LTC6811-1 datasheet:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6811-1-6811-2.pdf

thanks for any help

Comment: I expect that someone somewhere may have done this but that doesn't really constitute a valid question on this site. Plus, if you are serious about finding something out (other than whether something is possible (and it surely will be)) you should provide data sheet links to the devices and/or schematics where appropriate.

Comment: thanks Andy aka for your comment and optimism. I have edited the question and included links to the relevant datasheets.